# Angular 4 + typescript fail to deploy on heroku

Tags: angular, typescript, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my angular 4 app on heroku but it fails to dpeloy properly. Locally all works fine as expected.

Here the files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webcli2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot  --target=production"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.3",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.4",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.9.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "vue-carousel-3d": "0.1.18",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
     },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    }
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.get('/*', function (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/index.html'));
});

console.log('console listening');
```

Procfile
    web: npm start

About the error: I got this:

```
remote:        @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.6.1  was found instead. 
remote:        Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug  problems.
remote:        
remote:        Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.
remote:        
remote:        npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'
remote:        
remote:        To disable this warning run "ng set --global warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
remote:        
remote:       11% building modules 13/13 modules 0 activeTemplate parse warnings:
remote:        The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("
remote:        [WARNING ->]<template [ngIf]="!isClosed">
remote:        <div [class]="'alert alert-' + type" role="alert" [ngClass]="classes""): ng:///tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/alert/alert.component.d.ts.AlertComponent.html@1:0
remote:        Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationError in /tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/src/app/util/applicationError.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v5.x
remote:        Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationError in /tmp/ build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/src/app/util/applicationError.service.ts: (?).   This will become an error in Angular v5.x
Date: 2017-11-14T10:33:21.586Z
remote:        Hash: 5582f12f0052b6c3a94c
remote:        Time: 22622ms
remote:        chunk {0} styles.de3b0b246fb3804809f9.bundle.css (styles) 133 kB {3}   [initial] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {1} polyfills.3bc34265385d52184eab.bundle.js (polyfills) 86 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {2} main.e402deade8b026b7d50e.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {3} inline.ebdb3a382088c7f31aee.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in /tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/src/app/services/auth/user/user.service.ts (73,75): Value of type '() => any' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'. Did you mean to call it?
remote:        ERROR in /tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/src/app/services/auth/user/user.service.ts (82,39): Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
remote:        ERROR in /tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/src/app/services/auth/auth.service.ts (16,34): Cannot find module '../../util/applicationerror.service'.
remote:        ERROR in /tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/src/app/services/auth/auth.service.ts (111,5): Type 'Observable<void | {}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'.
remote:          Type 'void | {}' is not assignable to type '{}'.
remote:            Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{}'.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-133-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/.heroku/    node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/.heroku/node/bin/npm"  "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/  build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/.npmrc" 
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.11.3
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! webcli2@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --aot  --target=production`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the webcli2@0.0.0 postinstall script 'ng build --aot  --target=production'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the webcli2 package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     ng build --aot  --target=production
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs webcli2
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls webcli2
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_1e53727d0184bdda3a3ece784898bf98/npm-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

So looks like that it is not able to install a previous typescript version, in this case, heroku has already 2.6.1, but the one I have on the file is 2.3.3

This is the cause of this error's ?

Locally I got:

```
Brunos-MBP:webcli brunolopes$ ng build -aot
 12% building modules 18/18 modules 0 activeWarning: Can't resolve all 
parameters for ApplicationError in 
 /Users/brunolopes/development/workspace2016/
webroot/winpi/webcli/src/app/util/applicationerror.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v5.x
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationError in 

/Users/brunolopes/development/workspace2016/
webroot/winpi/webcli/src/app/util/applicationerror.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular 
v5.x 
Template parse warnings:
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("
[WARNING ->]<template [ngIf]="!isClosed">
<div [class]="'alert alert-' + type" role="alert" [ngClass]="classes""): ng:///Users/brunolopes/development/workspace2016/webroot/winpi/webcli/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/alert/alert.component.d.ts.AlertComponent.html@1:0
Date: 2017-11-16T07:51:16.467Z                                                          
Hash: 32f3a3b7f72daf78e799
Time: 53961ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB 
[entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 515 kB {vendor} 
[initial] [rendered]
 chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map 
(polyfills) 
217 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 153 kB 
{inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.43 MB 
[initial] [rendered]
Brunos-MBP:webcli brunolopes$
```

Thanks

B

Comment: Can you do ng build --aot locally?

Comment: Yes with few warnings but ends successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Changed angular version to 4.4.6 and it solved the issue.

That is the one on my local environment by mistake I had 4.2.4 on the package.json.

Thanks all!